# What is "posix isolation"?

Tags: posix, virtualization, mesos, lxc, mesosphere

The `Mesos` Slave is using `posix isolation` by default:

```
......  
I0105 06:26:28.479199  1869 containerizer.cpp:142] Using isolation: posix/cpu,posix/mem,filesystem/posix  
......
```

What is "`posix isolation`"? I can't google it.

Comment: Virtualization questions, not related to software development, are better asked at ServerFault (or SuperUser).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mesos uses isolators in its containerizer to isolate the resource usage of each started task. The `posix` isolators provide separation of task as standard Unix processes. Each Mesos task is running under `mesos-executor` process, which makes sure that the task is running. These don't really perform any actual isolation but only report the current resource usage of running tasks.

Under Linux, there is also [cgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) isolator available that can do actual isolation (CPU and memory).

You can find more about [Mesos Containerizer](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/containerizer/) and [Docker Containerizer](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/docker-containerizer/) on the [Apache Mesos website](http://mesos.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0):

When we have different databases in a single server,
posix isolation is to make sure that files, processes and databases are protected from other users and data that may exist in the same system